# The ideal way of using CSS Grid with wrappers?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Unfortunately, I've had a very hard time finding examples of people using CSS Grid with a wrapper. This is what I came up with.

The wrapper portion of my website has max-width of 1340px. Our website uses 5 columns, so each column is 268px. Note that, some elements do bleed out of the wrapper, to cover the whole width.

```
// WRAPPER CONFIG
$wrapper-width: 1340px; // Based on design PSD
$column-width: 268px; //1340 / 5 = 268. Our design uses 5 columns.

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:
    minmax(1rem, 1fr) //space left of wrapper
    minmax(min-content, $column-width) //column with 268px width
    minmax( min-content, calc(4 \* #{$column-width}) ) // column with 1072px width
    minmax(1rem, 1fr); //space right of wrapper

    grid-template-areas: //example layout
    "A A A A"
    ". B B ."
    "C C C C"
    ". D D .";
}
```

Any comments, and critiques? If you know a better example/resource, I'd love to know.

Comment: layout looks fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6eb9hkdx/ are you facing issues while using it?

Comment: I'm not really facing an issue, but I just haven't seen this type of column spacing much else in online resources, so I felt like I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Seems fine to me. CodeReview.SE might be a better platform for this sort of question